# How to fix “Permission denied to access property "invoke”"?

Tags: java, eclipse, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Code  -

```
Select Gender = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='gender']")));
Gender.selectByValue("Male");
```

Error   -

```
`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: **Permission denied to access property "invoke"** 

Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' 

System info: host: 'COMP2-PC', ip: '192.168.1.9', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_91' 

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver 

Capabilities [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false, appBuildId=20161123182536, version=50.0.1, platform=XP, proxy=Proxy(), command_id=1.0, specificationLevel=0.0, acceptSslCerts=false, processId=2380.0, browserVersion=50.0.1, platformVersion=6.1, XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=windows_nt}] Session ID: c1e4da76-9f21-45aa-a1b8-f21a9e8dd088     

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)    
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)    
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)    
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)    
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException
(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:150)     
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode
(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:115)     
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode
(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:45)  
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute
(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)  
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute
(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)     
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute
(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)  
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute
(RemoteWebElement.java:272)     
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.getAttribute
(RemoteWebElement.java:124)     
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.<init>(Select.java:52)     
at AppInformationTest.main(AppInformationTest.java:70) `
```

While trying to automate (Selecting a dropdown value) with selenium webdriver I ran into this problem.

- **Tools Versions are*:**
      Java - 1.8.0_91, 
      Eclipse - Oxygen Release (4.7.0), 
      Mozilla Firefox-50.01, 
      Gecko driver-v0.17.0-win64 ....Please help me to sort out!

Comment: Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow Works. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.   You must post your code and any error messages, but as text and not as images.  There is not enough information in your post for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is browser specfic issue , try it with Chrome. Follow this link to see more

[Reference Link for your issue](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/7170)